# Link resizing of DataGrid to Form Width resize

Tags: vb.net

Working with VS2017, in VB, I have a simple DataGridView in a form that I have Locked set to False, all works fine.  Except...

Is there a way to link the DataGridView size to the resizing of the form? In particular, is there a way to link a particular column width to the resizing of the form window?  I know I can set the Column.Resizable property to True to any or all of the columns, but is it possible to allow the Grid and a particular column to stretch with the form window?

[image: Grid]

Comment: Looking into the docking and anchor properties of the the Datagrid control.  Using either will allow the grid to resize with the parent without any other requirements

Comment: Changing the AutoSizeMode to Fill on a particular column along with setting the Anchor on the grid to Top, Left, Right seems to have resolved my issue.  I will play with the other column settings a bit more to get it perfect.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes providing all the relevant tags. Is this a Windows Forms application? If so, the question should be tagged as such. In that case, is this really a `DataGrid`, or is it actually a `DataGridView`? The former still exists but the latter pretty much made it obsolete in 2005. When someone says `DataGrid`, many will tend to assume WPF, because virtually no one still uses the `DataGrid` in WinForms.

Comment: Sorry, yes, DataGridView in a Window Form.